# I'm working on Spring Authorization Server with Spring cloud gateway while building the application with Gradle contextLoads() test case is failing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-authorization-server, spring-cloud-security

I have disabled the eureka client registration in testcases but unable to disable the spring oauth2 client in testcases here is the code

```
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    properties = {
      "eureka.client.enabled=false",
      "spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.spring.issuer-uri=some-url"
    })
class GatewayApplicationTests {

  @Test
  void contextLoads() {}
}
```

I have tried `spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.spring.issuer-uri=some-url` but still I'm facing the below error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception with message: URI is not absolute
```

can anyone help me to fix this error